# Error con el StatusBar en ionic para IOS

Tags: android, typescript, ionic, ios, cordova

Ya importe `import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx'`;

y tengo la siguiente configuración en el app.components.ts en android me respeta muy bien la configuracion, pero ios no lo respeta para nada.

```
  `initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#33000000');
    });
  }`
```

De antemano se los agradezco y espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0):

En el constructor agregué el `platform: Platform` y en el *initializeApp* la siguiente condición y funciono:

```
if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
    this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
}
```